# How to install WRF on a Mac?

Tags: models, wrf

I would like to install the [WRF model](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/) on my Mac computer.

Where can I find up to date and step-by-step instructions on how to install it?

Comment: - Best is to ask wrfhelp.

Comment: Why are you asking? The manual does not mention Mac as a supported platform.

Comment: people do run WRF on macs..

Comment: People usually use Linux, but I'm sure its possible. You'll need the necessary compilers, though. From my experience, you'll likely need the licensed compilers, like Intel or PGI.

Comment: WRF builds and runs just fine with the free GNU compiler, in case commercial compilers are not accessible. You can expect the GNU build to be up to twice as slow relative to Intel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WRF Forum [here](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/wrfv3.4/testing.html) describes some testing using a Mac, and they report success with 2 setups:

Mac 64-bit running OSX, with Intel chips, g95 gcc version 4.0.3 (g95 0.92!)

Mac 64-bit running OSX, with Intel chips, PGI pgf90 10.3

There is also some additional information on installing ARWpost on a Mac found on the [WRF Forum](http://forum.wrfforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=5563).

Separately, there is a blog dedicated to your question [here](http://macwrf.blogspot.com/) and instructions on github [here](https://github.com/Toberumono/WRF-Setup-Script).  Also, if you see the tutorial [here](https://catastrophescience.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/compiling-wrf-arw-mac/), you can see a method that requires you to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).